# Writing an excel sheet using poi and hashmaps

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap, apache-poi, concurrenthashmap

I am attempting to write an excel sheet using POI and hashMaps. My code successfully creates and populates an excel sheet but not all of the information is written to the sheet. In debug mode it seems to write 5 key, value pairs and then loops to the start at key [0]. Can someone tell me where the mistake is in my logic?

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(make + " sheet");
        int rowNum = 0;
        ConcurrentHashMap <Integer, String[] > data = new 
                        ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String[]>();

        data.put(rowNum++, new String[] {"VIN", "Make", "Model", "Year", 
                        "Major Group", "Caption", "Cap Filter", "Illustration",
                        "Illus Filter", "PNC", "Part Name", "Part Number", "Quantity",
                        "Part Filter"});

        for (Part p : plist){
            String PNC = p.getPNC();
            String quantity = p.getQuantity();

            if(vFilterId.contains(p.getId())) {
                data.put(rowNum++ , new String[] {vinId, make, 
                                    model, year, group, caption, capFilter, illusName,
                                    iFilter, PNC, p.getName(), p.getPartNumber(), 
                                    quantity, "NONFILTERED"});

            } else {
                data.put(rowNum++ , new String[] {vinId, make, 
                                    model, year, group, caption, capFilter, illusName,
                                    iFilter, PNC, p.getName(), p.getPartNumber(), 
                                    quantity, "NONFILTERED"});

            }

        }
        int rowIndex = 0;
        Set<Integer> keyset = data.keySet();
        for (Integer key : keyset) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
            Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellIndex = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellIndex++);
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            }

        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            workbook.write(fos);
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("XLS sheet written.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return ReturnConstants.SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The out put I am getting is only three rows of data but when I run the same and print to a csv sheet I get 4060 rows returned any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How many entries do you have in that HashMap?

Comment: I am inputting 13 strings into the array per key, I need it to be dynamic to allow varying amounts of parts coming in, since there can be thousands or ten thousands of parts per ViN.

Comment: I was asking what is the result of `data.size()` once the data has been inserted? Does it contain the number of lines you're expecting?

Comment: It does end with a size of 3 and not what I am expecting it should have a result of 4060 for this particular VIN. For some reason it loops all the way to the start of the method, I am not sure why, If this seems like a bad question I am fresh out of college.

Comment: What is the result of `plist.size()` ?

Comment: @rhennigan What is the size of `plist` ?

Comment: it ends with a plist size of three but as the program is running the console out put throws out various values for plist and for data sizes.

Comment: @rhennigan try using `fos.flush();` before `fos.close();`

Comment: @Prabhaker adding fos.flush(); did not correct the problem

Answer (score 0):

You're using a map to store data representing rows in a table. You'd be better off using a List since maps are generally not sorted (i.e. the order of the entries might change over time).

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(make + " sheet");
List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

data.add(new String[] {"VIN", "Make", "Model", "Year", 
        "Major Group", "Caption", "Cap Filter", "Illustration",
        "Illus Filter", "PNC", "Part Name", "Part Number", "Quantity",
"Part Filter"});

for (Part p : plist){
    String PNC = p.getPNC();
    String quantity = p.getQuantity();

    if(vFilterId.contains(p.getId())) {
        data.add(new String[] {vinId, make, 
                model, year, group, caption, capFilter, illusName,
                iFilter, PNC, p.getName(), p.getPartNumber(), 
                quantity, "NONFILTERED"});

    } else {
        data.add(new String[] {vinId, make, 
                model, year, group, caption, capFilter, illusName,
                iFilter, PNC, p.getName(), p.getPartNumber(), 
                quantity, "NONFILTERED"});

    }

}
for (int rowIndex=0; rowIndex<data.size(); rowIndex++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex);
    Object[] objArr = data.get(rowIndex);
    int cellIndex = 0;
    for (Object obj : objArr) {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellIndex++);
        cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Guilaume This code gives the same results at my original code.

Comment: You said that plist contained 3 elements but you're expecting it to contain thousands, the problem is clearly elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine without debugging your code, but from what you described it seems like your keyset variable contains only 3 entries, which is why you are outputting only 3 rows. So the first thing I would do would be to display (using System.out.println) data.size() and keyset.size() to see how big they are. I am guessing one or both are only of size 3.

Did you show all the relevant code? I think perhaps not, because, for example, your if statement seems redundant as you output the same thing regardless of whether you execute the if code or else clause.

I do agree with the first answer that there is no need to use a HashMap; an ArrayList will work just as well. But, as you discovered, that has nothing to do with why you are only seeing 3 rows.

Sorry I can't be more helpful, but I think some debugging on your part with System.out.println will go a long way in discovering what the problem is.